# Can anyone break down what this assembly code does?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, x87

The following code is some rudimentary calculation in an old racing game. Its models downforce, by checking the car's current speed. There is a downforce coefficient (which I traced at the third line down) which is multiplied somewhere by the car's speed, which increases the vertical force on the tire. I think this is for the two front tyres.

Could someone break the equation down into simple terms for me? I only partly understand what I am looking at...

```
GAME.exe+58620C - 8B 54 24 0C           - mov edx,[esp+0C]
GAME.exe+586210 - 8B 44 24 04           - mov eax,[esp+04]
GAME.exe+586214 - D9 04 90              - fld dword ptr [eax+edx*4]
GAME.exe+586217 - 8B CA                 - mov ecx,edx
GAME.exe+586219 - 6B C9 34              - imul ecx,ecx,34
GAME.exe+58621C - 8D 4C 01 08           - lea ecx,[ecx+eax+08]
GAME.exe+586220 - 8B 01                 - mov eax,[ecx]
GAME.exe+586222 - 85 C0                 - test eax,eax
GAME.exe+586224 - 74 46                 - je GAME.exe+58626C
GAME.exe+586226 - 83 F8 01              - cmp eax,01 { 1 }
GAME.exe+586229 - D9 44 24 10           - fld dword ptr [esp+10]
GAME.exe+58622D - 75 0F                 - jne GAME.exe+58623E
GAME.exe+58622F - D9 05 C8975300        - fld dword ptr [GAME.exe+1397C8] { (0.00) }
GAME.exe+586235 - D8D9                  - fcomp st(0),st(1)
GAME.exe+586237 - DFE0                  - fnstsw ax
GAME.exe+586239 - F6 C4 41              - test ah,41 { 65 }
GAME.exe+58623C - 7A 2C                 - jp GAME.exe+58626A
GAME.exe+58623E - D8 51 1C              - fcom dword ptr [ecx+1C]
GAME.exe+586241 - DFE0                  - fnstsw ax
GAME.exe+586243 - F6 C4 41              - test ah,41 { 65 }
GAME.exe+586246 - 75 07                 - jne GAME.exe+58624F
GAME.exe+586248 - DDD8                  - fstp st(0)
GAME.exe+58624A - D9 41 1C              - fld dword ptr [ecx+1C]
GAME.exe+58624D - EB 0F                 - jmp GAME.exe+58625E
GAME.exe+58624F - D8 51 18              - fcom dword ptr [ecx+18]
GAME.exe+586252 - DFE0                  - fnstsw ax
GAME.exe+586254 - F6 C4 05              - test ah,05 { 5 }
GAME.exe+586257 - 7A 05                 - jp GAME.exe+58625E
GAME.exe+586259 - DDD8                  - fstp st(0)
GAME.exe+58625B - D9 41 18              - fld dword ptr [ecx+18]
GAME.exe+58625E - D8 49 14              - fmul dword ptr [ecx+14]
GAME.exe+586261 - D8 41 10              - fadd dword ptr [ecx+10]
GAME.exe+586264 - D8 49 04              - fmul dword ptr [ecx+04]
GAME.exe+586267 - DEC1                  - faddp 
GAME.exe+586269 - C3                    - ret 
GAME.exe+58626A - DDD8                  - fstp st(0)
GAME.exe+58626C - C3                    - ret
```

Comment: We can't see where the branches go because you didn't show addresses.  A disassembler like `objconv` can disassemble into asm source with branch labels, making it much easier to sort out conditional behaviour.  (Storing the status word and testing it is an alternative to `sahf` and using jp (unordered) or ja / je / jb.)

Comment: We also don't know what pointer values are in integer registers, or what FP constant is getting loaded by `fld dword ptr [GAME.exe+1397C8]`.

Comment: I just added the addresses to each line. Does it help?

Comment: Yeah, that makes it possible to get started and see the branch targets .  It would help more if you matched up the numeric addresses yourself and labeled the branch targets, as well as just the pure numbers, especially any backward branches (since those are normally the tops of loops).  There are a lot of branches here, not easy to keep it all in your head while looking for the pattern.  Single-stepping through it and watching FP register values change would probably be helpful.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I am doing this correctly...Adding breakpoints on each stage.

Comment: ESP+0C = [-0.01] ///
ESP+04 = [Pointer location starting at 00A0000, which contains each car's physics data] ///
ESP+10 = -1.00

Struggling with the EAX and EDX values at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the code are no revealed and alot of it is using windows kernel offsets who are not documented like:

```
1.mov edx,[esp+0C] / mov eax,[esp+04]
2.je GAME.exe+58626C / jne GAME.exe+58623E / jp GAME.exe+58626A etc
3.fld dword ptr [eax+edx*4]
```

99% of the code is hidden no one will be able to help you you need to provide the whole code

NOTE: the address is just place in your code while runtime and it will not help

Comment: What is the best way to find the values for EAX and ESP etc.?

Comment: debugging them and see were they going to with breakpoints

Comment: but mov edx,[esp+0C] is windows kernel function and its points to PEB_LDR_DATA

Comment: Why do you think loading EDX from your own local stack space has anything to do with the Windows kernel?  `mov edx, [esp+0xC]` is a perfectly normal instruction that can appear in normal compiler-generated code for accessing a local variable.

Comment: @PaulTaylor, the value for `ESP` is irrelevant as it's a moving target anyway.